# Eliminate `Indeterminate` in a list of conditions

Tags: filtering

In an examplary  list of conditions

```
list={0 <= Sqrt[2] r + 2 y <= 20, y <= 6 + x, x <= 7 + y,0 <= Sqrt[2] r + 2 x <=22,
(Indeterminate | Indeterminate) \[Element] Reals,Indeterminate <= -1, Indeterminate <= 0,x <= 7 + r + y}
```

Mathematica produced several conditions which make no sense.

My question:

How to delete all conditions which contain `Indeterminate`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select[FreeQ @ Indeterminate] @ list
```

> ```
> {0 <= Sqrt[2] r + 2 y <= 20, 
>  y <= 6 + x, 
>  x <= 7 + y, 
>  0 <= Sqrt[2] r + 2 x <= 22, 
>  x <= 7 + r + y}
> ```

Comment: How easy (if you know how ;-) ) , thank you very much!